# Calculate the power consumption

Tags: power, power-electronics, esp32, energy

I have project put the ESP32-S2 in active mode for 10 second and then go to modem-sleep mode. I want to compute the power consumption for the active mode.  According to [this,](https://diyi0t.com/reduce-the-esp32-power-consumption/) the ESP32-S2 current consumption is 190 mA.  If I multiply (190 * 10) is that correct? How can I compute it?

Comment: Have you tried googling how to calculate power?

Comment: It appears that what you want is the [**energy** consumption.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/electricalenergy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Power equals volts × amperes.**

So if the power rail is 3.3 volts and the current is 190 mA, then power equals 0.627 watts.

What you have calculated are milli-ampere minutes.

Comment: Thanks Andy, this is very clear, now for the link shared by @JRE if I need to compute the energy consumption I should compute it as [(energy=3.3V * 0.19A * 10s) =6.27 joule] is this correct?

Comment: @oleva that is exactly correct; joules consumed in ten seconds is 6.27

Comment: I have another question please, in some references I read the energy consumption in (mWh) how can compute it in this unit?

Comment: @oleva:  1Wh (watt hour) = 3600 joules. One joule is one watt second.

Comment: If I convert (6.27 J = 0.001742 Wh) and then (0.001742 Wh *1000) =1.742mwh. is this correct?

Comment: @oleva:  Your math looks correct.

Comment: @oleva I think I see your confusion now. A power of 627 mW over 1 hour is just 627 mWh (or 2257.2 joules).

Comment: Sorry Andy, how can get on this (2257.2 joules)?

Comment: I'm trying to interpret your question in the comment above and have answered it in the simplest way I could imagine. Try asking the question again but with more detail @oleva

Comment: I am just wanted to compute the energy consumption in (mWh) therefore I convert (Joule to watt and then to mwh )(6.27 J = 0.001742 Wh) and then (0.001742 Wh *1000) =1.742mwh

Comment: milli-ampere seconds, not minutes @Andyaka

Comment: @oleva Basically you are averaging out the energy. If your device runs for 10 seconds it uses 6.27 joules. If it runs for 10 seconds every hour, that's 6.27 joules per hour; if it runs for 10 seconds every day that's 6.27 joules per day; etc. If your device runs for 10 seconds and another 10 seconds and another 10 seconds and never stops running (so 3600 seconds every hour), then it's 2257.2 joules per hour. But I don't think that is what you meant.